# Color issue with URDF and multiple visual tags

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build a URDF model that comprises different components with different colors. However, I don't necessarily want every component to be its own link; I'm just aiming for a higher level of visual fidelity. I saw here that it's possible to have multiple `<visual>` tags within a given `<link>`:

http://answers.ros.org/question/10913/multiple-visual-entries-in-urdf/

...and indeed, this works. However, subsequent `<visual>` tags appear to have their  tags ignored, and instead get painted the color of the first `<visual>` tag. In other words, if I do this:

```
  <link name="link1">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="4" radius="1"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="black_metal">
        <color rgba="0.1 0.1 0.1 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="2" radius="5"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="gold">
        <color rgba="1 0.549 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
```

...then BOTH my cylinders end up getting colored as the "black_metal" material. Is this a bug, or am I simply using URDF in a manner which was not intended?

EDIT: I'm using Hydro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154816/color-issue-with-urdf-and-multiple-visual-tags/) by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13689 on 2014-04-18

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this is current limitation of rviz, I created patches at https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/pull/812, but not seems good. Need someone to rewrite better one.

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2014-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-09-15**:
Cool, thanks for doing that! I'll check it out. If your PR gets accepted and merged, I'll select this as the answer.